# PytestWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report

Tags: pytest, coverage.py

I am trying to get a coverage report on my code by running the following command:

```
python3 -m pytest --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov=main/lambda_function tests
```

I am running the command in the terminal of pycharm within the repo and my main code is located under main/lambda_function.

I did have a .coveragerc configured correctly but once I relocated the lambda_function file under main, my coverage report stopped working:

```
[run]
source =
    lambda_function
    rds_config
[paths]
source =
    src/lambda_function
[report]
show_missing = true
precision = 2
```

I have attempted to add main/ but I get the error:

```
Coverage.py warning: Module main/lambda_function was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of [--cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#reference) should be a path as documented:

> **`--cov=PATH`**
>
> Measure coverage for filesystem path. (multi-allowed)

Try changing the coverage path to the containing directory **main**

```
python3 -m pytest --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov=main tests
```

Or try using the python module name notation of using dot `.` and without the file extension **main.lambda_function**

```
python3 -m pytest --cov-config=.coveragerc --cov=main.lambda_function tests
```

Comment: So it runs now? Check your tests. Probably it doesn't call your code. Perhaps you mocked everything?

Answer (score 0):

I use pytest with PyCharm and a pyproject.toml instead of .coveragerc

With the configuration

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
# Also see
# https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#pyproject-toml
# https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html
# If you want to see console output from tests, include -s flag
addopts = [
    '--cov=src',
    '--cov-fail-under=98',
    '--cov-report=html:pytest',
    '--cov-report=term-missing',
    '--junitxml=report.xml'
]
```

I got the error

```
...\python-3.10.2.amd64\lib\site-packages\pytest_cov\plugin.py:308: CovReportWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
```

**A.** For me the **solution was to remove the option** '--cov=src' :

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
# Also see
# https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/customize.html#pyproject-toml
# https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html
# If you want to see console output from tests, include -s flag
addopts = [
    '--cov-fail-under=98',
    '--cov-report=html:pytest',
    '--cov-report=term-missing',
    '--junitxml=report.xml'
]
```

**B.** I also thought I would have to include following setting in pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.coverage.run]
source = ['src']
```

However, including that or not in pyproject.toml does not seem to make a difference.

**C.** In order to apply pyproject.toml for PyCharm, I specified its path it under the project settings:
Pylint => Path to pylintrc
(There is no explicit option for pyproject.toml but nevertheless it works.)

Answer (score 0):

I got `WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.` because I forgot to prepend my test file with `test_`
i.e. my filename was `app.py` when it should have been `test_app.py`